# Finding objects from Parse Query using localDataStore results in Network not found?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, local-datastore

I'm doing a project where i use `parse` version **1.6.5** and `localDataStore`, In `AppDelegate` i have enabled for `localDatastore` like

```
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];
[Parse setApplicationId:@"AppId" clientKey:@"ClientKey"];
```

and in my `ViewController` i have a condition whether the app runs for firs time, if first time, retrieving from server and pin all objects to local. Else retrieve from `localDatastore` my code

```
if ([self isAppLaunchingForFirstTime]) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Category"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed!" message:@"error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        } else {
            if (objects.count) {
                [self.categoryArray addObject:objects];
                [self.collectionView reloadData];
                [PFObject pinAllInBackground:objects block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if (succeeded) {
                        NSLog(@"Pinned successfully");
                    }else {
                        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Pinning" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                    }
                }];                    
            } else {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"No Records" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
            }
        }
    }];
} else {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Category"];
    [query fromLocalDatastore];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed!" message:error.description delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        } else {
            if (objects.count) {
                [self.categoryArray addObject:objects];
                [self.collectionView reloadData];
            } else {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"No Records" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

**Problem** is first app runs successfully and shows the retrieved objects in collectionView whereas from second time the app has a long running background task as i'm retrieving from `localDataStore` it checks for network connectivity and it retries for 5 times to fetch each object. Does `localDataStore` requires network connectivity.

**Error Log in Console :**
     this is the error repeatedly occurred for 36 times to fetch 7 objects.

```
[Error]: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x1e56e2a0 
{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Category, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Category,
NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.,
NSUnderlyingError=0x1e57fae0 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."}
(Code: 100, Version: 1.6.5)
```

Comment: tried ur same code at my end with my class. Working for me

Comment: may i know in which device you installed your app, mine is ipod touch with iOS6.1

Comment: i did not installed on a device .just checked on simulator

Comment: oh okay. my class has relation and pointer column, did your class have those columns

Comment: no i don't have any relation and pointer column. but it's not the problem ,local datastore don't need internet connection, so your data should be fetched

Comment: would you mind to verify if your isAppLaunchingForFirstTime method working as expected?

Comment: @Simon i already verified it's working correctly.

Comment: did you solve your problem? try the lasted Parse SDK, if the problem persist you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. But seems that isAppLaunchingForFirstTime flag is not set off after objects successfully pinned

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to report this on Parse bug report:   https://www.parse.com/help#